# How do i make setprecision effect only one variable and not all in my code

Tags: iomanip

[hey this is my code and its results im new to c++, my assignment is have to have "value" display 2 digits after the decimal point but its also making "years" display 2 digits after the decimal points. how do i make it effect only the variable "value".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udmzY.png)

ive tried "cout << setprecision << fixed << value; and that just messes it up

Comment: Hi,  welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your code as text, not as an image. Check out [ask] when you can. Thanks!